# Reveal/Collapse Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The result in jsfiddle may not work, but it does in my documents.

http://jsfiddle.net/hXzrA/

What is working is that my text is hidden, and when I click on **Read More...**, it reveals more of the text in the paragraph.  If I click on **Read More...** again it collapses the text in the paragraph back to the normal state.

What I having been trying to figure out is:

1. a mouse over the **Read More....** link. Kinda like a Blue color highlight so that people know it's mouseover.
2. When the text is revealed, **Read More...** text should disappear and at the bottom of the now revealed text, should be **Collapse text...** (same blue highlight on mouseover).  The Collapse should restore the text back to it's collapse state.
   How do I achieve this in:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){

     var open = false;
     $('.reveal').click(function() {
       if (open) {
         $(this).animate({height:'20px'}); 
       }
       else {
         $(this).animate({height:'100%'});
       }
       open = !open;
     });
   });
   ```
3. Also, if you are able to get the text to implode/explode on reveal/hide, that would be so great too. I have been trying and trying, but couldn't get it to do that.

Comment: Its not working in jsfiddle cause you're using jquery but it is not selected.

Comment: Have you seen the jQuery Expander Plugin? it is [HERE](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/demo/index.html)

Comment: @Ragnarokkr: Please don't put things in inline code blocks that aren't code.

Comment: @animuson I thought that since it was part of the HTML code it should have been written as inline code. My bad, sorry. I'll check it up with more carefully for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look how simplified it could be at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/syEM3/

Javascript:

```
$('.reveal').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

EDIT: 
For the effect of reveal / collapse:

```
$('.reveal').click(function() {
    $(this).slideUp(100).next().slideToggle();
    $(".collapse").slideDown(100);
});

$('.collapse').click(function() {
    $(this).slideUp(100).prev().slideToggle();
    $(".reveal").slideDown(100);
});
```

Comment: Is there a way that when I hover, it doesn't move the divs around it? Hover area is too large

Comment: @KGKG sorry, but I didn't understant your question ... are you talking about the slideUp() ? on .reveal click ?

Comment: When I hover over the "Click Here to Read More..."  or "Collapse Text"  I have another <div> section and it moves whenever I hover.  How do I prevent that following <div> section to be completely independent (or how do I make the hovers completely strictly to the "Click here"/"Collapse here" text?

Comment: Ahh, I see, your not talking about my example right? (Because it doesn't happen in my example right?) Probably the best solution is to change the hover css, to have the same dimensions as the normal state, but I can help you if you show me that code in a fiddle...

Comment: No it doesn't happen to your exact code. Here is MY updated version of your code. Notice the hover over. http://jsfiddle.net/jX9G3/   Basically I added a bit more CSS positioning, and I have more html on the bottom of Collapse text.

Comment: @KGKG That float right is messing your code :) when you set an element as float, that element will have undefined dimensions... give me a minute and I'll try to fix this...

Comment: @KGKG here is a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/jX9G3/1/ HTML is not easy... You should read a lot first to understand the logic. By the way, don't forget to close your elements <div><p> </p></div> :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not `animate` to `100%`, you need to calculate element's original height first than manipulate the height.

[**Here is working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/wey3a/1/)

```
var orgHeight = parseInt($('.reveal').css('height'));
$('.reveal').css('height','20px');

$('.reveal').click(function() {
    var target = parseInt($(this).css('height'));

    if (target != orgHeight) {
        $(this).animate({'height':orgHeight+'px'},500);
    }else{
        $(this).animate({'height':'20px'},500); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For hover effect, just use CSS:

```
.readmore:hover, .readless:hover {
   text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px blue;
}
```

As for the separate links, I think it's easier just to put them in your markup:

```
<a class="readmore">Click Here to READ MORE...</a>
TEXT TEXT TEXT
<a class="readless">Collapse Text...</a>
```

Then just `.show`/`.hide` `.readmore`/`.readless` as appropriate based on `open`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/hXzrA/4/

Answer (score 0):

stick a :hover on your selector and then put the rule for the hover. That should be in your css, not the jquery function.

wrap a span around your "Read More" text with a class and in the jquery, on the click function above you can do something like:
$('spanClass').hide();

and just the opposite:
$('spanClass').show();